# android:tabStripEnabled=“false” doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I'm having a problem with the *TabWidget* Layout.

How can I combine the tab with the content as it always shows this fading edge:

[image]

The graphics are perfect. I set the `android:tabStripEnabled="false"` but still it keeps showing me the line that separates between the tabs and the frame layout.

this is the XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <include layout="@layout/action_bar" />

<TabHost

        android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:showDividers="none" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/grger"
                    android:fadingEdge="none" >

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TabHost>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Adding you layout XML will probably get you more help :-)

Comment: I've added it you can check them now ,, thanks